# Node.js app in a docker container not reachable over Internet "Connection refused"

Tags: node.js, oracle, docker, connection

I am struggling for a quite some time making a node.js app to be accessible over Internet.
The docker container is running on a port 9000.
The host machine is an Oracle Linux virtual machine one, on the Oracle Cloud. I have enabled the port 9000 there.

In the container I run the node.js app with:

```
sh-4.2# node index.js
Starting application
Initializing database module
libDir = /usr/lib/oracle/19.3/client64/lib
Initializing web server module
Web server listening on Host:0.0.0.0, Port:9000
```

Check the docker container process from within the Oracle Linux host:
docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
8504964aa23c        227d64c853db/domaevid-server   "sh"                About a minute ago   Up About a minute   9000/tcp            mystifying_babbage
```

And testing the connection on the host is giving back the error:

```
[opc@instance-20210318-1902 ~]$ curl http://public.ip:9000/api/home
curl: (7) Failed connect to public.ip:9000; Connection refused
```

The content of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN  yum -y install oracle-release-el7 && \
    yum -y install oracle-instantclient19.3-basiclite && \
    yum -y install oracle-nodejs-release-el7 && \
    yum-config-manager --disable ol7_developer_EPEL && \
    yum install vim-enhanced -y && \ 
    yum -y install nodejs && \
    npm install && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum
RUN echo "export xxx" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "export xxx" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "export xxx" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "export xxx" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "export xxx" >> ~/.bashrc
RUN source ~/.bashrc 
COPY /_docker/ORACLE/NETWORK/ADMIN/* /usr/lib/oracle/19.3/client64/lib/network/admin 

COPY . .

EXPOSE 9000
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

What else should be done so the node.js app is reachable over Internet?

Kind regards,
Dime

Comment: @DavidMaze Setting it as a duplicate of a question with 16 answers and none of them marked as accepted might be confusing.

Comment: Almost all of the answers to that question, including those with several hundred upvotes, mention Compose `ports:` or the `docker run -p` option.  It seems like a reasonable canonical question for this Docker fundamental.

Comment: One tip: 19.3 is very old.  The current is 19.14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't mapped port 9000 in the container to port 9000 on the host when you started the container.

The 'Ports' section of the `docker ps` display looks like this

```
PORTS
9000/tcp
```

but should look like this

```
PORTS
0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp
```

You map the port by adding `-p 9000:9000` as a parameter on the `docker run` command (before the image name). This maps port 9000 on the host to port 9000 in the container, so it's reachable.